# Is SuperGrubDisk similar to EasyBCD but is a self boot disc?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, supergrubdisk, easybcd

Is SuperGrubDisk similar to EasyBCD which can fix the boot option menu?

So the difference is that SuperGrubDisk is a self boot disc, and uses the Linux GRUB boot mechanism, while EasyBCD needs to run on Windows (can it self boot up and run?), and uses a different boot mechanism (Windows's mechanism?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have most of the answer.

[Super Grub Disk](http://freshmeat.net/projects/supergrub) is a bootable floppy or CDROM that is oriented towards [system rescue](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), specifically for repairing the booting process. Super Grub Disk is simply a [Grub Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) with a lot of useful menus. It can activate partitions, boot partitions, boot MBRs, boot your former OS (Linux or another one) by loading menu.lst from your hard disk, automatically restore Grub on your MBR, swap hard disks in the BIOS, and boot from any available disk device. It has multi-language support, and allows you to change the keyboard layout of your shell.

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/EasyBCD+Documentation+Home) on the other hand, is a bootloader modification tool.
On its own, it is not a bootable tool.
However [a bootable edition is discussed in this EasyBCD forum thread](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=2215).
Some points from the author on a bootable EasyBCD edition.

> - EasyBCD runs on Windows 98, ME, NT, 2k, XP, Vista, and Server 2008
> - A LiveCD doesn't need to be powered by *nix platforms. A Live CD running WinPE 1.0 or 2.0 would have access to mounting all the drives, NTFS, etc.
> - GParted is being developed once more: GParted Live CD Being Developed Once More - The NeoSmart Forums
> - HnS and EasyBCD will always remain separate utilities for Windows (i.e. if there were a Live CD, things might be different). Reason: HnS is for use with legacy operating systems and won't be needed forever. EasyBCD is the future.
> - I am busy.
>
> So it's a mix of things. It's certainly possible. It does have its advantages.
>   But I really need to sit down and get EasyBCD 2.0 out of the door before anything else.
>
> The BCD cannot be touched from within Linux. Reason: the BCD lives in a registry hive. I've covered this before in multiple threads, but in short, the risks associated with
>   a) mounting an NTFS partition on Linux for write purposes
>   b) manually opening a registry hive on any machine, Windows or otherwise
>   c) editing the registry hive manually (if it's even possible, I don't know if tools exist to do this) are crazy-high and not ones I fancy taking on.